# How do I make this generic class typesafe?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a typescript function
`register(values, f)`
where values is of type `{ key1: string, key2: string }[]`
and f is a function which takes in a variable `context`.
`context` is a generic class that provides a function getValueForKeys, whose inputs are `key1` and `key2`, which correspond one of the `{ key1: string, key2: string }` objects passed into register via the values parameter.
How do I make this generic class typesafe, such that all the keys accessed from context in f's function definition are ones that are passed into `register()`? I'm hoping to make the context inferred from usage of `register()`, so that a developer writing a function to be registered doesn't need to pass in types to the generic.

I tried to make the solution as follows:

```
type Key = { key1: string; key2: string; value: any };
type Values = Key[];

type Key2FromKey1<T extends Values, K1 extends T[number]['key1']> = T[number]['key1'] extends K1 ? T[number]['key2'] : never;

class Context<T extends Values> {
  constructor(private keys: T) {}

  getValueForKey<K1 extends T[number]['key1'], K2 extends Key2FromKey1<T, K1>>(key1: K1, key2: K2): any {
    const matchingKey = this.keys.find(k => k.key1 === key1 && k.key2 === key2);
    return matchingKey ? matchingKey.value : undefined;
  }
}

function register<T extends Values>(
  values: T,
  f: (context: Context<T>) => void
) {
  const context = new Context(values);
  f(context);
}

register([{ key1: 'foo', key2: 'bar', value: 'value1' }, { key1: 'biz', key2: 'baz', value: 'value2' }], (context) => {
  // This should succeed
  const value = context.getValueForKey('foo', 'bar');
  // This should fail
  const value2 = context.getValueForKey('biz', 'buzz'); // Error: Argument of type '"buzz"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"baz"'.
});
```

However, this seems to be failing for both value and value2, saying of 'bar' and 'buzz' that
`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKvRKm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your definition of `Key2FromKey1<T, K1>` doesn't actually extract the right elements of the input array type.  Since `T[number]` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Key`-ish types, you could use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter that union for the ones whose `key1` is assignable to `K1`, and then [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) those members for the `"key2"` property:

```
type Key2FromKey1<T extends Values, K1 extends T[number]['key1']> =
  Extract<T[number], { key1: K1 }>['key2'];
```

Another issue is that by default the compiler will infer just `string` for a string-valued property; so the value `{key1: "foo"}` will be interpreted as `{key1: string}` and the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"foo"` you care about is lost.  You need to give the compiler a hint that the first argument to `register()` needs to have its type inferred more narrowly, as if the caller used [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  We can do that by using [a `const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) for `T`:

```
function register<const T extends Values>(
  // -----------> ^^^^^
  values: T,
  f: (context: Context<T>) => void
) {
  const context = new Context(values);
  f(context);
}
```

Oh, and that means array literals will be inferred as [`readonly` tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types).  This is fine, but `Values` is `Key[]` and would reject `readonly Key[]`.  So we'll make one more change to allow it:

```
type Values = readonly Key[];
// ---------> ^^^^^^^^
```

Okay, those are the changes. Let's test it out:

---

```
register(
  [
    { key1: 'foo', key2: 'bar', value: 'value1' },
    { key1: 'biz', key2: 'baz', value: 'value2' }
  ], (context) => {
    const value = context.getValueForKey('foo', 'bar'); // okay
    const value2 = context.getValueForKey('biz', 'buzz'); // error!
    // ----------------------------------------> ~~~~~~
    // Argument of type '"buzz"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"baz"'.
  });
```

Looks good.  `T` is inferred as

```
readonly [{
    readonly key1: "foo";
    readonly key2: "bar";
    readonly value: "value1";
}, {
    readonly key1: "biz";
    readonly key2: "baz";
    readonly value: "value2";
}]
```

so the call to `getValueForKey("foo", ⋯)` constrains the second argument to `"bar"`, while the call to `getValueForKey("biz", ⋯)` constrains the second argument to `"baz"`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQN5QNbwIwC4oGdgAnASwDsBzAbg3gCY9DTKaA3AQwBsBXCPdsggC+VAFChIUAGpde+JFCIR2AEwD2ZTgjggA2gF0xAeiNQAtBcuWAfFAB6Dxw9EmoINdyjqyAcmBQAdwF-YDUoMCVWCDJ-ACJ2eQBjDUJYglBOaHYiInYQeQAzIjUAW0C1InRyClEXUwAVAAtoArVOTjUA6qhExoEKaBJ5YGaoEhKwCuBgqAAjEmBxcGgdOgAxYpKdLAAeeqgIAA9gaJV5GR4IfAAaWCwD49P5et0ybhLZiCJ9XR9MECwPn0tkQoigUAAosdcolgHtXu9Pt9bmh-rg7lAhNZfv86ECxHUoABNDxeEgqXz+BLoKCtIhQEZDObcfwlEgURpU+QBCDtJaSC68DalHT4PYPE5kM7SWRXW4wLDyuggsGQ6HsWHwt4fL76FG0AF4BW3XFGuiY7E+DiXIG1RKcBLyADCGhOx3FR0l0sFV1sKFVyTITG4sIqAAoIiQOCcDfg8PUAJSoTG1cEDYA+tYVHQ7BUSp5QF7apE-P7YIFK-NS+SrYVbbB7eVYazWMNoo2Kg0MWB0BM4VXgzObUWNu5K2wAHyg3ClEAK5AgKlQA56KVZ7GAvWqOgUjPwADp-gf51K20hbOhD9gkIhkGioAAyB8YK8gc23u-0BNicHgpTAbgiDIKASg3LdKB3AB+ECwMabd4H3a1eCgPAZxUOcFxUH8UyEWoChnWESA0RQIAoIYTiIHZA0IQsq29WV8FbVVXCsViLFsJw7CgHZLDcUkghiBkwnIAovnSZgKCgTgFi+LgGWWQoKgZUZ72fXFwmKMB8FVJCrnja5VQKPAw0DN1gDwF0Yk9PZrCTRBbFYNRyVEJN-XBaj-FMz0FDICAAigSyzLDXT8G-QyTNdT0wtw0QlDIwgvjDVVdBXVFsDwHxWjUHwTXoDLZmyHKoF0jLdMBTEDN-ZN2ygHx5gALyK01aoKxrbhK2rdLxFNwT1KAIqs447L9FcPOK2UFC84593TTNs3gMNMrUbLbjqwrvygVw1HQPJRrXcbLnfVdBuAGaIAzWUsyIHRFoaoq6u4erGo21wvmKIgAEIVxYtjfr+-7-tsAA-EHQe+0wAEEiAod5on8NQCnkyQfFiWZHvq2IfDGeQyDULl8HZMh2FmTIhPCbJ2BKc6xIRpHoBR1rMf3VUhG-IA)